# Giving permissions to a SQL Job to be able to access/modify folders and files on a different server

Tags: sql, t-sql, permissions

I have a sql job on SERVER01.

Part of the job is to access a folder located on a different server:

\\SERVER02\Files

I need to be able to create folders and files under it as well as modify/delete files.

The \\SERVER02\Files folder is being shared with several different accounts.

If I go to SERVER02 and try to UNC path to \\SERVER02\Files, it'll ask for a password.

Since the servers are in two different domains, I need to specify the domain for the account:

DOMAIN\accountName

password

Questions:

What is the correct way for me to set this up so that the job will have access to the other server so it can manipulate the files at \\SERVER02\Files ?

This is very confusing so I'm trying to get it right. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have this same issue in our own environment, because we have two domains that have to share resources.  The technically correct solution is to setup a trust between the two domains so that user logins are mapped across the domains.  If you're like us and can't setup a domain trust, you can try some of the following solutions:

1. Login under the account that the SQL job runs under on `SERVER01`, and use the [Credential Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms918995.aspx) to create a login to `SERVER02` with the other domain's user / password.
2. Under the account that SQL job runs, create a network share to the UNC path with the credentials embedded: `NET USE M: \\SERVER02\Files [password] /user:[domain\user]`.  You will have to make sure this path is always mapped before the job runs, and use `M:` for your path.
3. If you have a specific process/command you need to run that accesses the network path, you can start that particular process using `runas` to authenticate with the second domain's credentials: `runas /netonly /user:[domain\user] "/path/to/mytask.exe"`.  This prompts for the password, but that can be piped in with `echo [password]|runas ...`

Comment: Thanks for this mellamokb. I'll give it a try and let you know the results!